# Reference Request for Infinite Alternating Sums

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, reference-request

I am wondering if anyone can recommend me references to the following sum.

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^a\Big(\frac{1}{(2k)^n}-\frac{2}{(2k+1)^n}+\frac{1}{(2k+2)^n}\Big),$$

in which $n$ is a non-negative integer and $0\leq a \leq n.$ I have encountered this expression while deriving the asymptotic expansion for a certain function but I am stuck on where to proceed from here.

Comment: The quantity in the big parentheses looks like  a second derivative.  Does that help?

Comment: The second derivative of what function?

Comment: It looks like a partial function decomposition of the second derivative of $\frac 1{(2k+1)^n}$ with interval ($h$) of $1$.